# Unwanted characters in input stream of java socket

Tags: java, sockets, http

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 18:46:37 GMT
Connection: close

bc  // Unwanted  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request type="POST">
    <FirstName>Aditya</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Rameshwarpratap</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Singh</LastName>
</Request>
0  // Unwanted
```

how do I remove those unwanted chunk length at start and end of response in Java Socket input stream
Right now I am reading input stream like this.

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(is);
    int i;
    while ((i = din.read()) != -1) {
        char c = (char) i;
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: It is not unwanted data, it is part of the HTTP protocol for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Use an HTTP API instead of raw sockets, so you don't have to re-implement all the various features of HTTP. Alternatively, learn what `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is and how it works, then implement it correctly in your code. More completely, **learn HTTP**, though using an HTTP library instead is highly recommended. --- *FYI:* `bc` is hex for `188`, which means that the first chunk is the following 188 bytes. The second chunk length of 0 means the end of data for this HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

This representation of the data is correct.  You can calling into an HTTP server, and it is going to return any number of data encodings.  If you look at the documentation on the [Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) header you can see that there are several other representations that the server could opt to send you.

For instance if the header was set to 'gzip, chunked' not only would the chunking be present, but the interior payload would be gzip compressed.

You could use the built in Java URL classes to perform this fetch

```
URL oracle = new URL("https://.......");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Or for more advanced usages of HTTP, you might want to use something like the [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/) library.  Both of these solutions will abstract away most of the intricacies of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I was able to fix it using ChunkedInputStream for html,javascript and CSS file. But ChunkedInputStream is not working for image responses.